# Cannot get listitems to reload from database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I have written a small app that has a `ListView` with a custom adapter. Each row contains some `Button`s, which will change background color when clicked, and I got the list items to be clickable as well by putting

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in the xml of the list items. But now I have this weird bug where clicking on the list item reverts all clicked `Button`s back to their original colorless state. How can I get the `Button`s to keep their color?

Details:

Part of the custom adapter:

```
View.OnClickListener onButtonClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View button) {
        View listItem = (View) button.getParent();
        final long DBid = (long) listItem.getTag();//database ID

        final Button b = (Button) button;

                    sqldataDataSource datasource = new sqldataDataSource(context);
                    datasource.open();
                    datasource.updateButton(DBid);
                    datasource.close();
                    b.setBackgroundColor(0xFF386F00);

    }
};
```

As you can see, I change the background color AND change the database entry, so when the whole list is reloaded, the `Button` keeps its color (another part of my custom adapter):

```
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hrlistitems, parent, false);

    Button b = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.HRlistB);
    b.setOnClickListener(onButtonClicked);

    if(!(values.get(i).getB().equals(""))){
        b.setBackgroundColor(0xFF386F00);
    }
    return rowView;
}
```

This works fine when going to another activity and coming back to this one. The buttons are created colored as expected.

So my guess was that the list is recreated from the original listItem array when an item is clicked, which is why I tried to fix this by reloading my database, like so (from my activity):

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    datasource = new sqldataDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    listItems = datasource.getOnlyRoutes(id);//this works fine
    Collections.sort(listItems, HallenRoute.vergleichen());

    if (mListView == null) {
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewHalle);
    }
    adapter=new customAdapter(this, listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int pos, long nid) {
            listItems.get(pos).increaseCount();
            datasource.updateCountHR(listItems.get(pos));
            listItems = datasource.getOnlyRoutes(id);//fix I tried, doesn't work
            Collections.sort(listItems, HallenRoute.vergleichen());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}
```

But this doesn't work.

How can I get the `ListView` to either not reload on `ItemClick` or reload properly (i.e. from database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to reload the whole data for every `Button` click.

In your `Button` click you're just updating the data base and not your adapter dataset `values`, this is why you always get the old background color.

```
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hrlistitems, parent, false);

    Button b = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.HRlistB);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View button) {
          View listItem = (View) button.getParent();
          final long DBid = (long) listItem.getTag();//database ID

          final Button b = (Button) button;

          sqldataDataSource datasource = new sqldataDataSource(context);
          datasource.open();
          datasource.updateButton(DBid);
          datasource.close();
          //b.setBackgroundColor(0xFF386F00); no need for this line, getView() method will take care of the background
          //update your adapter dataset, eg: values.get(i).setB("newColor");
          notifyDataSetChanged(); // to refresh your adapter

        }
    });

    if(!(values.get(i).getB().equals(""))){
        b.setBackgroundColor(0xFF386F00);
    }
    return rowView;
}
```

**PS:** It's better if you save your "database ID" in your Model object not as a `View` tag.

Comment: This works! It also improves maintainability because I have the colors all in one place now. ... But I don't really understand the PS, where should I put the id?

Comment: Your *values* is a list of what (the item class)?

Comment: Ah, ok, the item class of course stores the `DBid`, but to be able to access it in the `onClick` method I put it into the tag. Now that I think about it, it makes more sense to put `i` in there, so that I can use `values.get(i).getId()` to access it. I had changed the tag to a `long[]` to pass `DBid` *and* `i`, which of course makes absolutely no sense :D Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!